# How to create an Entity Data Model for generic types?

Tags: entity-framework, entity

I'm trying to make something similar to this with my Entity Data Model (model first approach), but I've no clue how to achieve it, so I need some ideas. Thanks beforehand.

```
public class JournalAttribute<E>
{
    public String name { get; set; }
    public E value { get; set; }

    public JournalAttribute(String name, E value)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The EF doesn't support generically-typed entities.